# What's wrong with my asp update code ?, no error, but nothing change too

Tags: asp.net

I need help for my asp update code, there is no error while running, but it not change th data too...
here is my asp update code

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE merk SET Merk=@a Where MerkID=@b", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", namamerek.Value.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", idmerk);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    reset();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
    lbleror.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    errm.Visible = true;
}
```

Gridview "SelectedChange" events :

```
        GridViewRow gvrow = gridmerek.SelectedRow;
        idmerk = gvrow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
        namamerek.Value = gvrow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        merksebelum = gvrow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        invokeedit();
```

Comment: HAve you checked the database? whether the query updates the data?

Comment: yes, I try the query on database too, it change the data, but when I apply to asp code, it not change

Comment: What happens if you remember the `@` symbol in your `AddWithValue` calls? Have you attached the debugger through your code and stepped through line by line? Does the program flow as expected?

Comment: previously, i have 2 aspx page, i just copy code from another aspx page to this page, in another page that code work perfectly, but when I try run that code on this page, no error and no change too in database

Comment: Could be that `MerkID` is wrong.  Put a profiler trace on the database and see if your SQL command is received, and if it has the correct values.